# What should I do with a Rails 1.1.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade

I'm going to have to move a Rails 1.1.2 app, because my hosting contract is going to expire.

I haven't done anything to the code for a few years and I would like to know what would be the best way to upgrade my app. Many things have changed since then, RoR isn't using a localization plugin anymore but i18n, etc..

I would like to re-deploy it to a new hosting like Heroku, and that will not allow me to use rails 1.1.2.

Should I try a rake rails:update or do I need to re-create a new project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the early Rails 1.2 stages a lot of methods were aggressively deprecated and the routing system was radically altered, so to upgrade your application will take a fairly serious investment of time to ensure that everything is still working. Anything prior to 1.2.5 requires this kind of overhaul to make it work in anything post 2.0.

If you're good with search and replace, you can do this much more efficiently as it's mostly a case of the route names changing throughout your controllers and views.